# .htaccess url rewrite not formatting properly

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently I working through my localhost in MAMP. I have read and research for the proper way to allow  .htaccess file url rewrite and was successful. But now, the file is not formatting the links at all as desired. For example I have three pages `index.php`,  `about.php` and `contact`. I am using MVC for the frame working of my site. Is this a problem with the code in the .htaccess file or my localserver?

Currently links look like this when going from one page to another:

`localhost/mvc/index.php?`

`localhost/mvc/index.php?p=about`

`localhost/mvc/index.php?p=contact`

.htaccess should format the links to look like this:

`localhost/mvc/index/?`

`localhost/mvc/about/?`

`localhost/mvc/contact/?`

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Turn on the engine:
RewriteEngine on

# Set the base to this directory:
RewriteBase /mvc/

# Redirect certain paths to index.php:
RewriteRule ^(about|contact|this|that|search)/?$ index.php?p=$1

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Create a php file with the content `<?php phpinfo();` and search for `mod_rewrite` and see if it is on the `Loaded Modules`.

Comment: @Prix Yes its in the loaded modules.

Comment: Try removing the `<ifmodule...></ifmodule>` and see if u get a 500 error or any changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your existing .htaccess code fully with this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
# Set the base to this directory:
RewriteBase /mvc/

# Redirect /mvc/index.php?p=page to /mvc/page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+mvc/index\.php\?p=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/? [R=302,L]

# Redirect /mvc/index.php to /mvc/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+mvc/index\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /mvc/ [R=302,L]

# Internally forward certain /mvc/page/ to /mvc/index.php?p=page
RewriteRule ^(about|contact|this|that|search)/?$ /mvc/index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: +1 Thank you, but there is two things that are missing from the desired format. The index page still shows like this: `localhost/mvc/index.php` how can I remove the `.php` extension and a forward slash to like `localhost/mvc/index/`,  `localhost/mvc/about/`,  `localhost/mvc/contact/`

Comment: Check the edit now. `localhost/mvc/index.php` should ideally become `localhost/mvc/` instead of `localhost/mvc/index/`

Comment: thank you!, it is still showing the pages without a forward `/` in front. For example: `http://localhost/mvc/about` instead of `http://localhost/mvc/about/`. How come?

Comment: I had updated the code to use trailing slash `/` can you try different browser and let me know.

Comment: You are right, But there is another issue that has now appear: Once in the correct page: `http://localhost/mvc/about/` when i try to go to contacts it redirects to: `http://localhost/mvc/about/index.php?p=contact`

Comment: It is still redirecting to a non existing url. The problem seems to be  in the second `RewriteCond`.

Comment: What is the URL you;re entering in your browser?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. The url links were relative i had to append to them `http://localhost/mvc/` and now is working.

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
RewriteRule ^(about|contact|this|that|search)/?$ index.php?p=$1
```

with :

```
RewriteRule ^(about|contact|this|that|search)/\?$ index.php?p=$1
```

I just escaped the ? with a slash because, otherwise, you don't do this, the question mark will be interpreted and will means that the slash before it is optinal.

Comment: I don't think he wants to redirect. He didn't mention this term. But I agree with you that the better way is to remove the ? and to use QSA, but I made what he wanted.

Comment: True but that would not work because the `RewriteRule` does not evaluate query string so it would not match the `?` and the rule itself would fail.

Comment: @LucasWillems well i change it to that but somewhow it is not formatting anything at all.

Comment: @CodeLover1985 remove the `?` and add at the end of your rule `[L,QSA]`

Comment: and if you try this : "RewriteRule ^(about|contact|this|that|search)$ index.php?p=$1". Can you access to localhost/mvc/about ?

Comment: @Prix I did so but no results

Comment: @LucasWillems I tried that but nothing. I even tried taking of the `.php` from the index file to see if that worked and it gave an error

Comment: Are you sure you can rewrite url ?

Comment: Yes, I checked in the loaded modules and its there.